# How to remove unneccessary decimal place in textbox? C#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a textbox which is binded to a specific database table column. This column is formatted to be numeric with 4 decimal places.

What I want is displaying Integer in textbox without decimal places but displaying float number with decimal places.

e.g. 1) Display in textbox (45), Data in database (45.0000)

2) Display in textbox (45.45), Data in database (45.4500)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to Mark's. One will print 45, the other will print 45.45.

```
        float num = 45.4500f;
        float num2 = 45.0000f;


        string strnum = num.ToString().TrimEnd('0', '.');

        this.textBox1.Text = strnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Custom Numeric String Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

i.e.

```
Single data1 = 45.0000f;
Single data2 = 45.4500f;
string sFormat = "#0.####";
textBox1.Text = data1.ToString(sFormat); // displays 45
textBox2.Text = data2.ToString(sFormat); // displays 45.45
```

Comment: I believe he/she doesn't want to see 45.0000 if the number in the database is an integer. Simply 45.